# Adjust Format of List of Algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir, algorithms, tocloft

I'm using an existing LaTeX template for a thesis and am trying to match the List of Algorithms to the List of Figures.  I have already applied some formatting changes, but there are a few attributes that I am having trouble manipulating.

Here is a sample of the LoF:

---

[image: LoF]

---

And here is a sample of the LoA:

---

[image]

---

There are three attributes that I still need to edit in the LoA:

- The algorithm number needs to be flush with the column heading
- The indentation after the algorithm number needs to be reduced slightly
- The spacing between the dot separation needs to be reduced in the LoA

After much googline, I was able to find a couple attributes Ideally, I would like to know where the source code is located that produces the LoA so that I can view it myself and any documentation associated with the construction of the LOA, but I am also interested in knowing how to edit these three specific attributes.

---

**EDIT**

I'm working on a minimal working example, but the template is a bit convoluted.

Here is the main .tex file:

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[labelsep=period, font=singlespacing, skip=12pt, format=hang,
justification=RaggedRight, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\floatname{algorithm}{\textnormal{Algorithm}}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\textnormal{\arabic{algorithm}.} }

\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS\\
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\par\nobreak {\normalfont ALGORITHM \hfill PAGE}\par\nobreak
}



\begin{document}


\listoffigures
\clearpage
\pagebreak
\listofalgorithms
\clearpage
\pagebreak

\pagestyle{plain}

\mainmatter
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
%\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent CHAPTER \par}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.75in}{1.25in}{*}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:tf}
tf(t, d) = \frac{| t \in d |}{| words \in d |}
\end{equation}
\vspace{\linespace}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:idf}
idf(t, D) = \log \frac{|D|}{|\{d \in D : t \in d\}|}
\end{equation}
\vspace{\linespace}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:tfidf}
tfidf(t, d, D) = tf(t, d) \times idf(t, D)
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\caption{Formula for calculating the TF-IDF}
\label{fig:tfidf}
\vspace{\linespace}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Building a C4.5 Decision Tree}
\label{alg:C4.5}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\STATE Check for base cases
\FORALL{$a$ $\in$ attributes}
\STATE Find the normalized information gain ratio from splitting on $a$
\ENDFOR
\STATE Let $a\_best$ be the attribute with the highest normalized information
gain
\STATE Create a decision $node$ that splits on $a\_best$
\STATE Recurse on the sublists obtained by splitting on $a\_best$, and add those
nodes as children of $node$

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Here is the .sty file that contains many custom layout commands:  [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jkqs6dnrw5vxyzm/thesis.sty)

The .sty file is particularly full of random bits and peices, but I'll try to simplify them as much as I can (edits should occur in real-time via Dropbox).

---

**EDIT 2**

Through much googline, I was able redefine a couple commands in the LoA:  `thealgorithm` and `listofalgorithmname`.  I think my main issue is that *I have no idea where these commands are documented, declared, or used in the first place*, so I have no idea how I can redefine other commands.

**Where are these commands declared?**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B I'll try to create a working example, but the template I'm using contains several hundred lines of custom commands.  I'll do my best.

Comment: erh, `tocloft` does not make sense with `memoir`, use the `memoir` equivalent tools (loading `tocloft` with memoir does not load onything from `tocloft`, also remember that some of the `memoir` equivalents have different manes in `memoir`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my train of thought in terms of analysing the problem...

I first try and create a *minimal* example that replicates your problem. This means I keep an eye open for the things that  you generate, and package that could influence them. For that, [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) and [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) stand out:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{algorithm,tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\cftdotsep}{1}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

That was easy...

Now we try and understand the difference between how `\listoffigures` and `\listofalgorithms` generate there output. Well, to understand this, it seems like `tocloft`'s `\cftdotsep` has an influence on the former, but not the latter. Strange... Looking at the code of [`algorithms.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.dtx) - the source bundle for the `algorithm` package - it is clear that the `algorithm` float environment is generated by means of the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) with `\listofalgorithms` having the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\listof{algorithm}{\listalgorithmname}}
```

That is, `\listofalgorithms` actually just calls some `\listof` routine provided by `float`. So, let's look at `\listof`:

```
\newcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
    \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
    \float@listhead{#2}%
    \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
      \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
    \endgroup}}
```

Ahhh, with a call to `\listof{<name>}{..}`, it creates `\l@<name>` - the macro responsible for setting each entry inside the List of XX construct. From this I'm able to conclude that the in-line construction of `\l@algorithm` is most likely not compatible with `tocloft`, and that's why it's not affected in the same way.

The resolution is to attempt to make `\l@algorithm` act exactly like `\l@figure`. In TeX terms, this is as simple as `\let\l@algorithm\l@figure`. We can use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\listof` to always make `\l@XX` be equivalent to `\l@figure` (for any `XX`):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\listof}% <cmd>
  {\float@listhead}% <search>
  {\@namedef{l@#1}{\l@figure}\float@listhead}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above patch inserts a variant of the above-mentioned `\let` into the appropriate location of `\listof`.

Here's a minimal example showing the output:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{algorithm,tocloft}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\listof}% <cmd>
  {\float@listhead}% <search>
  {\@namedef{l@#1}{\l@figure}\float@listhead}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\cftdotsep}{1}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```