# Style \listofalgorithms from algorithm package

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, tocloft

I have some weird requirements for thesis formatting at my university. I was able to manage to mimic almost all of them, but List of Algorithms from `algorithm` package is something I cannot go through - I don't even know where to start looking. Basically what I want to achieve is to have same formatting for LoA like for LoF.

Minimum working example is below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{6pt}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\clearpage \large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0.0}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptertitlename}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{.}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $a \gets 0$
    \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{Alg}\label{alg:algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate [label=left:$m$,circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] (m) at (-12em,-4.em);
        \coordinate [label=below:$O$,circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] (O) at (2em,-10em);
        \draw[blue, ->, thick] (m) -- node[above] {} (O);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Fig}
    \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listofalgorithms
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following segment of code makes an entire copy of the macros involved with `\listoffigures`, applying them to a redefined `\listofalgorithms`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\l@algorithm\l@figure%
  \let\listofalgorithms\listoffigures% Copy \listoffigures
  \let\@cftmakeloatitle\@cftmakeloftitle% Copy LoF title
  % Update LoA-related macros
  \patchcmd{\listofalgorithms}{\@cftmakeloftitle}{\@cftmakeloatitle}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\listofalgorithms}{\@starttoc{lof}}{\@starttoc{loa}}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@cftmakeloatitle}{\listfigurename}{\listalgorithmname}{}{}%
  % Add per-chapter LoA space (similar to LoF)
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents}{%
    \addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents}{}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

Here's your example in action:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{6pt}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\clearpage \large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0.0}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptertitlename}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{.}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{algorithm,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\l@algorithm\l@figure%
  \let\listofalgorithms\listoffigures%
  \let\@cftmakeloatitle\@cftmakeloftitle%
  \patchcmd{\listofalgorithms}{\@cftmakeloftitle}{\@cftmakeloatitle}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\listofalgorithms}{\@starttoc{lof}}{\@starttoc{loa}}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@cftmakeloatitle}{\listfigurename}{\listalgorithmname}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents}{%
    \addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Alg}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It may be relevant to also add `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}`.

Comment: @Wener : Thanks. I tried your example. It does format the 'list of algorithms' in the same format as 'list of figures'. However, the word 'Figure' appears instead of 'Algorithm' in the toc as well as the list. What can I do?

Comment: @Abhinav: this helped me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186077/adjust-format-of-list-of-algorithms

Comment: @Abhinav: I can't replicate your issue with my example. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates that problematic behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

There are doubtless *many, many* reasons not to do this...

## *Caveat emptor...*

The idea is essentially to write the list of algorithms to the auxiliary files twice.

We let the `algorithm` package do its own thing: it has its own counter, its own contents lines, its own format. The lot. We just never print the list of algorithms it produces.

Instead, we modify the `algorithm` environment using `etoolbox` so that it increments *two* counters, writes *two* lots of information to the auxiliary files etc.:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{%
  \let\oldcaption\caption
  \renewcommand\caption[1]{%
    \oldcaption{#1}%
    \stepcounter{alg}%
    \addcontentsline{loalg}{alg}{\protect\numberline{\thealg}{ #1}}}}
```

This saves the old definition of `\caption` and then redefines it to also increment `tocloft`'s counter and write a contents line to `tocloft`'s auxiliary file. These are created in the usual way:

```
\newlistof[chapter]{alg}{loalg}{\listalgorithmname}
```

Hence, we can apply the same customisation to it as in the case of the list of figures:

```
\setlength{\cftafterloalgtitleskip}{6pt}
\renewcommand{\cftloalgtitlefont}{\clearpage \large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
...
\renewcommand{\cftalgaftersnum}{.}
...
\setlength{\cftalgindent}{0pt}
```

This is, of course, not a terribly efficient solution. For one thing, it wastes a counter. However, minimal testing suggests it can be made to work:

[image: lists of figures and algorithms]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}
\newlistof[chapter]{alg}{loalg}{\listalgorithmname}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{6pt}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\clearpage \large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\setlength{\cftafterloalgtitleskip}{6pt}
\renewcommand{\cftloalgtitlefont}{\clearpage \large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0.0}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptertitlename}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftalgaftersnum}{.}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftalgindent}{0pt}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{%
  \let\oldcaption\caption
  \renewcommand\caption[1]{%
    \oldcaption{#1}%
    \stepcounter{alg}%
    \addcontentsline{loalg}{alg}{\protect\numberline{\thealg}{ #1}}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $a \gets 0$
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Alg}\label{alg:algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate [label=left:$m$,circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] (m) at (-12em,-4.em);
    \coordinate [label=below:$O$,circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] (O) at (2em,-10em);
    \draw[blue, ->, thick] (m) -- node[above] {} (O);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Fig}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listofalg
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listalgorithmname}
\end{document}
```