# Undo page number alignment and remove dots from list of algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, algorithm2e, classicthesis

I am using the [classicthesis](https://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) theme and I am trying to make my list of algorithms the same format as my lists of tables and figures.
I am using the `algorithm2e` package.
Here is how it looks at the moment.

[image]

I have tried the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263778/style-listofalgorithms-from-algorithm-package) but they do not work, presumably because they use the `algorithm` package instead. Using the accepted answer, the list of algorithms takes the name of the list of figures, but doesn't list anything: [image]

The other answer just doesn't change anything at all.

Since the classicthesis template is massive, I am not sure how to provide a minimal working example... The following code reproduces the issue, with the original `classicthesis.sty` file from the classicthesis template.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\listofalgorithms

\newpage

Here is Algorithm \ref{alg:some_alg}.

\begin{algorithm}
    \For{something}{
        something else
    }
    \caption{Some algorithm.}\label{alg:some_alg}
\end{algorithm}

Here is Table \ref{tab:some_table}.

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    some line & some content \\
    some other line & some other content \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some table.}
    \label{tab:some_table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I wish to remove the dots from the algorithms table, as well as to undo the alignment of the page numbers so that it looks like the list of tables above.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I have tried to improve the question by providing a minimal working example.

Comment: Very good, +1. Surely someone will answer soon.

Comment: Looking at classicthesis.sty, I see that it is already set up for listings.  The code for this adaptation is rather extensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the tocloft command `\newlistof`.  The actual formatting is performed by `\l@algocf`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\newlistof{algorithms}{loa}{\listalgorithmcfname}%
    \renewcommand{\cftalgorithmsleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}%
    \renewcommand{\cftalgorithmsafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
    \renewcommand{\cftalgorithmspresnum}{\algorithmcfname~}%
    \newlength{\algorithmslabelwidth}%
    \settowidth{\algorithmslabelwidth}{\cftalgorithmspresnum~999}%
    \addtolength{\algorithmslabelwidth}{2.5em}%
    \cftsetindents{algorithms}{0em}{\algorithmslabelwidth}%
    \let\l@algocf\l@algorithms
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\listofalgorithms

\newpage

Here is Algorithm \ref{alg:some_alg}.

\begin{algorithm}
    \For{something}{
        something else
    }
    \caption{Some algorithm.}\label{alg:some_alg}
\end{algorithm}

Here is Table \ref{tab:some_table}.

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    some line & some content \\
    some other line & some other content \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some table.}
    \label{tab:some_table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the error:
```! Undefined control sequence.
l.57 \newlistof
               {algorithms}{loa}{\listalgorithmcfname}%
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: The error I get (now) is undefined \spacedallcaps, which is used by classicthesis, but I have no idea where it is defined.

Comment: Further research showed that \spacedallcaps was provided by mathpazo, but it appears to no longer be supported.

Comment: I got it to work by placing the code into my main .tex file, *not* in classicthesis-config.tex but afterwards, so that classicthesis.sty is already loaded.