# Formatting "List of Algorithms"

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

My school requires the list of Algorithms to be formatted the same way as the list of figures. I found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263778/9279). Upon trying [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263841/9279) answer from Werner, I did get the formatting spot on as shown in image:

[image]

However, the word 'Figure' appears in place of 'Algorithm' everywhere in Table of contents and the list-of-Algorithms. How can I replace the text 'Figure' with 'Algorithm' in these places?

Answer (score 1):

You may change names with the following commands

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{New Figure Caption Name}
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{New Figure Autoref Name}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures Modifyed}
```

However, I would suggest to use `\usepackage{listings}` and then rename the captions with

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Algorithms}
```

And using the command `\lstlistoflistings` to insert the list of all listings.
This approach does not mix figures and others objects you might have in your work.

You may insert external code with

```
% firstline = 1, lastline = 10, firstnumber = 1, nolol, 
\lstinputlisting[label = {alg:file_name}, caption = {Legenda}]
{file_name.m}
```

or copy and paste it internally with

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    insert code here
\end{lstlisting}
```

You may find some more advice at [How to put a list of code in appendix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529346/140133) and the links in it.