# Adding list of algorithms and list of listings to pittetd

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

My question is about adding a properly formatted `\listofalgorithms` (and later `\listoflistings`) to the [`pittetd`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pittetd) class.

I don't think it's possible to `\renewcommand` on `\listofalgorithms` to get consistent formatting (or is it?), so I'm trying to duplicate some of the `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` code. Here is what I have so far:

```
\newcommand\listofalgos{\clearpage
  \typeout{List of Algorithms}%
  \@ifundefined{@outlinefile}{}{%
    \hypertarget{prelim.7}{}%
    \protected@write\@outlinefile{}{%
      \protect\BOOKMARK
      [0][]{prelim.7}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}{}%
      \protect\begingroup\protect\makeatletter
      \protect\prepare@bookmarks7
      \protect\@input{\jobname.loa}
      \protect\endgroup}}
  \null\vskip 1in
  {\normalfont\bfseries\centering
    LIST OF ALGORITHMS\par}
  \par\vspace{54\p@}%
  \@starttoc{loa}\newpage%
  \@enable{preface}{the first chapter}}
```

The problems are now that

- there isn't proper spacing between the caption text and the page number,
- there shouldn't be paragraph-style indentation for each entry, and
- each entry isn't on a new line:

[image]

Is there a problem with the `loa` file?

```
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
\contentsline {algorithm}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Backpropagation for computing weight updates in a fully-connected neural network, going over one line}}{1}{algorithm.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
\contentsline {algorithm}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Static linear response approach within fragment-localized formalism.}}{3}{algorithm.2}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
\contentsline {algorithm}{\numberline {3}{\ignorespaces Continuation of algorithm\nobreakspace {}\ref {alg:solve-linear-response}}}{4}{algorithm.3}
```

It should look like the following (ignore the different coloring, that's just hyperref):

[image]

Can it be simplified in a manner similar to the following?

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\listof{algorithm}{\listalgorithmname}}
```

- What is wrong with the above code (placed after `\let\l@figure\l@table` in `pittetd.cls`)?
- Is there a similar approach for a `\listoflistings`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the solution in the question, except that it's missing something. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186135/94717) answer helped me figure it out. While the solution that doesn't involve modifying a `cls/dtx` file is the float patch, the underlying solution is to directly inherit the table format:

```
\newcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{\@floatl}}
```

by using

```
\let\l@algorithm\l@table
```

Here is the resulting code:

```
\newcommand\listoflistings{\clearpage
  \typeout{List of Listings}%
  \@ifundefined{@outlinefile}{}{%
    \hypertarget{prelim.8}{}%
    \protected@write\@outlinefile{}{%
      \protect\BOOKMARK
      [0][]{prelim.8}{LIST OF LISTINGS}{}%
      \protect\begingroup\protect\makeatletter
      \protect\prepare@bookmarks8
      \protect\@input{\jobname.lol}
      \protect\endgroup}}
  \null\vskip 1in
  {\normalfont\bfseries\centering
    LIST OF LISTINGS\par}
  \par\vspace{54\p@}%
  \@starttoc{lol}\newpage
  \@enable{preface}{the first chapter}}
\newcommand\listofalgos{\clearpage
  \typeout{List of Algorithms}%
  \@ifundefined{@outlinefile}{}{%
    \hypertarget{prelim.9}{}%
    \protected@write\@outlinefile{}{%
      \protect\BOOKMARK
      [0][]{prelim.9}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}{}%
      \protect\begingroup\protect\makeatletter
      \protect\prepare@bookmarks9
      \protect\@input{\jobname.loa}
      \protect\endgroup}}
  \null\vskip 1in
  {\normalfont\bfseries\centering
    LIST OF ALGORITHMS\par}
  \par\vspace{54\p@}%
  \@starttoc{loa}\newpage
  \@enable{preface}{the first chapter}}
\let\l@algorithm\l@table
```

The list of listings already seems to be formatted appropriately.

These provide `\listofalgos` and `\listoflistings` rather than `\listofalgorithms` and `\listlistoflistings`.